# Norway camping gas cartridges

Tags: norway, camping

I am travelling to Norway soon and plan to camp. Are gas cartridges with screw-on type or percing type are more  commonly available and can they be  purchased in gas stations? I fly to Bergen and would like to know where I could purchase them near Bergen.

Comment: This might generate more answers on [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can almost certainly buy them in outdoor stores in Bergen.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bet on you finding it in gas stations, but you *will* find it in [sporting/outdoor stores](https://www.google.com/maps/search/sporting+store+near+bergen/@60.4183319,5.2931916,13z/data=!3m1!4b1), and cheaper at stores such as [Clas Ohlson](https://www.clasohlson.com/no/store-finder) and Biltema. Clas Ohlsson stores are located in downtown Bergen, while Biltema is more car oriented cash'n'carry.

Comment: OBS hypermarkets and Europris shops also have gas cartridges. The smaller screw-in cartridges are less than half the price at Europris compared to Clas Ohlson. Be also aware that Clas Ohlson only has two types of cartridges and not necessarily the one you need.